# App freeze after I run the runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading

The app freezes after I tap on the start button. 
Something in the loop is not right without the loop the runable is working fine. I'am trying to update the textview with time and distance to location I am going to

```
public Runnable updatel =new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

     while(Double.valueOf(time)>=5)
     {
          map.clear();
          map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place));

          location = map.getMyLocation();

          myloc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

          map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myloc));

          String url = getDirectionsUrl(myloc, place);

          DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

          // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
          downloadTask.execute(url);
         try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
    }
};



btnalert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {        
            updatel.run();
    }
});
```

Comment: Read up on asynctask, basically you send a reference to the views via constructor and update onPostExecute (after the work has been done).

Comment: Shouldn't you call start instead of run? Where is the variable time increased?

Comment: the time change in the downloadTask

Comment: but before this to work i search for a location in the map so time has a value and its not null

Answer (score 1):

The runnable is still launched on your UI thread. You will need a Thread to not freeze your UI.
Do something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(YOUR_RUNNABLE);
t.run();
```

And it should be good.

Comment: i think this should be "t.start()" ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not (actually you cant) update ui like textview from another thread.Try to use asynctask

Comment: i update the textview in asynctask (downloadTask) but i want it to run it in a loop so it stays updated

Comment: to delay it the while